# Sending a constant rate data stream from Droid via TCP/IP

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

in my quest to learn Java / Android development, I’m running into lots of roadblocks. Mainly because I don’t really know much about threading and communication between threads/processes. I’m trying to stream the IMU data from an android device to a python application on a computer. Whenever the sensor values change, a sensor listener saves the current values into a variable for the network handler to access.

The network handler in turn is supposed to run on a timer, sending the values and a current timestamp at a more or less fixed rate of 33Hz (perhaps a bit fast? well, I’d be willing to accept as slow as 10Hz, but no slower than that). Anyway, when I tested this, I could see on the computer interface that the data isn’t nearly coming in at a steady pace of 30 per second, but rather comes in surges, sometimes not coming at all for a second, and overall accumulating quite the delay (ie. the later the values are, the more delayed they come in). I understand there might be some variability in the network and some lags, but I would at least like the overall pace to at least be correct, ie that it doesn’t get worse and worse the longer I’m sending.

Considering the devices are both on a common wifi network, and I’m capable of streaming 1080p video without any lags over wifi, I’m fairly confident that the protocol should be able to handle a 64 Byte string every 30ms without troubles. To eliminate the sensor reader as an problem source, I made a minimum working example that simply sends a string every 30ms, without any sensor reading. I basically got this code from various stackoverflow posts, and modified it until it more or less did what I wanted. The problem is that the network interface runs in an AsynchronousTask, for which I am uncertain how to access it once it has been started. My theory is that it’s wasting resources to open a new socket for every new data packet, but I’m unsure how to open the socket once in the background and then pass the values to it on a timer and tell it to send.

Here’s the basic activity I made to test this:

```
package com.jamesdoesntlikejava.motionlearning15;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class SendValuesActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_values);
        // creating timer task, timer
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask taskNew = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int counter = 0;
                int numsteps = 333;
                String params[] = new String[2];
                if (counter < numsteps) {
                    params[0] = "192.168.1.33";
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    params[1] = Long.toString(currentTime)+"blablabla";
                    new ServerCommunicationTask().execute(params);
                    counter++;
                } else  {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                }
            }
        };
        // scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sending Values in 1s...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskNew,1000,30);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_send_values, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is the class for doing the networking:

```
package com.jamesdoesntlikejava.motionlearning15;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ServerCommunicationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public final static int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 13337;
    // params are 0: the target IP and 1: the message to send.
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {

        String TCP_SERVER_IP = params[0];
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(TCP_SERVER_IP, TCP_SERVER_PORT);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            //send output msg
            String outMsg = params[1];
            out.write(outMsg);
            out.flush();
            //close connection
            s.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    }
}
```

Running on a Moto G LTE (updated 1st gen) with android 5.1. Any hints are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: TCP wasn't designed for constant rate data streams. The rate will vary based on sliding windows and the need to wait for ACKs. UDP is one of the transport protocols designed to deliver constant rate data, assuming it can be handled by the rest of the network path. Also, wireless is a poor medium for constant rate data streams since it is half-duplex, and you must yield the medium because of the fairness built into the Wi-Fi standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of AsyncTask and always opening new connection, you can use Thread.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServerCommunicationThread extends Thread {

    public final static int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 13337;

    private ArrayList<String> mMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    private String mServer;

    private boolean mRun = true;

    public ServerCommunicationThread(String server) {
        this.mServer = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (mRun) {
            Socket s = null;
            try {
                s = new Socket(mServer, TCP_SERVER_PORT);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

                while (mRun) {
                    String message;

                    // Wait for message
                    synchronized (mMessages) {
                        while (mMessages.isEmpty()) {
                            try {
                                mMessages.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        // Get message and remove from the list
                        message = mMessages.get(0);
                        mMessages.remove(0);
                    }

                    //send output msg
                    String outMsg = message;
                    out.write(outMsg);
                    out.flush();
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //close connection
                if (s != null) {
                    try {
                        s.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        synchronized (mMessages) {
            mMessages.add(message);
            mMessages.notify();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        mRun = false;
    }
}
```

You can keep the thread running with connection opened and send message when needed.

```
ServerCommunicationThread thread = new ServerCommunicationThread("192.168.1.33");
thread.start();
...
thread.send("blablabla");
...
thread.send("blablabla");
...
thread.close();
```

Please note that this code is not tested.

Comment: Thanks Milos, that works for me. Once the constant offset between device times is subtracted, comparing timestamps from the droid and the computer now gives me: "333  values, mean:  2.1261261261 ms, min:  0 ms, max:  123 ms". However I notice that sometimes I will just receive a half of a message. I guess this is an inherent risk with TCP/IP and I have to use some kind of delimiter after each message which I then detect server-side and use to separate the received stream?